# What is the error in the following code. It is supposed to make a matrix using lists

Tags: python

My code is not printing the given inputs in a matrix form.

For example with given inputs as 2 rows and 2 columns and data as

1

2

3

4

The output is

2

2

4

4

Here is the code:

```
from random import *
m=input ("Enter total number of rows")
n=input ("Enter total number ofcolumns")
l=range(m*n)
k=0
print "Input all matrix element"
for i in range(m):
    for j in range(n):
        l[k]=input("Enter new element")
    k=k+1

print "output is"

k=0

for i in range(m):
    for j in range(n):
        print l[k], '\t',
    k=k+1

print
```

Comment: Have you tried debugging?

Comment: And hint: look into your naming ... those single-char names for loop counters, hmm, maybe ok; also m and n ... but seriously "l"?! use names that say something about the thing they denote!

Answer (score 2):

as Ghostcat noted you have an indent/index error that you could have completely avoided this kind of C-programming style bug by replacing this whole code:

```
l=range(m*n)
k=0
print "Input all matrix element"
for i in range(m):
    for j in range(n):
        l[k]=input("Enter new element")
    k=k+1
```

by a simple list comprehension:

```
print "Input all matrix element"
l = [input("Enter new element") for _ in xrange(m*n)]
```

(`xrange` for python 2, `range` for python 3)

Comment: I was just waiting for the "real" python answer to shop; so I could learn something too. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Here:

```
 for j in range(n):
     l[k]=input("Enter new element")
 k=k+1
```

That increases `k` ... not often enough!

As you have **one** index to walk over the whole array, you need to increase it within the inner loop!

```
 for j in range(n):
     l[k]=input("Enter new element")
     k=k+1
```

And hint: the reason that that you get the results printed as one row; is .. again because your single `print` that should do the new line happens **too far outside**. You also need to pull that one level **down**:

```
for i in range(m):
    for j in range(n):
        print l[k], '\t',
        k=k+1
    print
```

Comment: I like the "fix it yourself" side of the answer. +1 (so it was indentation error after all)

Comment: Well, that was because I hit "submit" too early. And maybe you are right, and I should delete that second edit ... you know, if the solution is to add a bunch of spaces, doesn't that mean: "should be closed as typographical error" in the first place ;-)

Comment: right. seriously I liked the "not often enough" which tells it all. But in that case, I try to answer outside of the box, like I just did now

Comment: thank you. i got the right output but need to work on right format of printing. right now it is printing in one row and not as a matrix

Comment: See my update. And sorry, same mistake. You really really should spent **more** time on thinking what your code is doing; and making experiments. Asking other people to explain such super simple things ... means that you continue to make such mistakes. You learn 10 times more when you spent the time to solve the puzzle yourself. But keep in mind that I helped again; when you start wondering which answer to accept ;-)